# Условие на php с url

Tags: php, условия

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы этот код выводился по определенному url?

```
$res .= '<div class="col-md-2"><a title="' . $item['name'] . '"' . (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],trim($item['url'],'\t\n\r\0\x0B')) == 0 ? ' href="ссылка' . $item['url'] . '/"' : '') . ' class="tabs-cell ' . (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],trim($item['url'],'\t\n\r\0\x0B')) != 0 ? 't-cur' : '') . ' ' . ($item['id'] == 248 || $item['id'] == 249 ? 't-mods' : '') . '">
            <img src="ссылка' . $item['url'] . '.png" alt="' . $item['name'] . '">
            <div itemprop="name" class="category-tabs--title">' . $par['title_tabs'] . '</div></div></a>';
    }
    $res .= '</div></div>';

    return $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`<>в этой переменной храниться страница с которой пользователь перешел или если он делал запрос с другого сервера `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` 
если страница формируется на текущем сайте то `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` и все что вам остается это написать проверку на одну из этих переменных

Comment: Страница формируется на текущем сайте. Можно все-такие увидеть? Просто не особо понял

Comment: <?if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'index.php'):?>
$res .= '</div></div>';
echo $res;
<?endif;?>